# Remove index.php of codeigniter

Tags: apache, codeigniter, centos

Yes, another one of these. I've tried everything I could find on the search with no luck.

In my httpd.conf (running centos and apache2):

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName www.domain.com
ServerAlias domain.com *.domain.com
DocumentRoot /var/www/html/domain.com
</VirtualHost>
```

in my htaccess in /var/www/html/domain.com:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

Nothing seems to be working.

I've tried adding

```
RewriteBase /
```

I've tried switching the last line to:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve here?

Comment: @praseodym He's trying to take the index.php out of CodeIgniter URLs.

Comment: Correct. I'm trying to go from http://domain.com/index.php/features

to http://domain.com/features

Comment: The CI directions have not helped, nor have any replies here so far. http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/urls.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to make sure that in your virtual host you have:

```
    <Directory "/path...to directory">
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
        Allowoverride all
    </Directory>

    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
        RewriteEngine on
    </IfModule>
```

Comment: Fixed. This really needs to be in the CI docs. I've seen it around, but wouldn't think any of this would affect it...

Comment: @Sheldon Kennedy It used to be in the CI documentation in the Wiki on Github. But someone took it out. 

Without the "Allowoverride all" part, Apache won't read your .htaccess files at all. Useful for other apps that need .htaccess files.

Comment: Thanks. I was unaware of this. I thought the one directive (AccessFileName) in the httpd.conf was to allow .htaccess

Answer (score 0):

The rules in the original post (and in the CI user guide) can be used to allow URLs to work without `/index.php/` in them, but will NOT remove `/index.php/` from existing URLs.

You can set `$config['index_page'] = '';` (removing `index.php`) in the CI config to remove `index.php` from CI-generated URLs.

If the original rules do not work, please give these rewrite rules a try:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [QSA,L]
```

Comment: He still needs changes in his httpd.conf

Comment: I don't really see why the virtualhost settings will matter. Apache will respond with a server error if `RewriteEngine on` fails or certain lines in `.htaccess` are not allowed.

Comment: Because he needs the "Allowoverride all" part or else Apache won't even read the .htaccess files.

Answer (score 0):

Two points of advice:

1.) Be sure you are saving/editing the .htaccess file into the root of your project folder, and not the .htaccess in your /applications folder. Such that, if my applications folder was at, project/application, don't edit the project/application/.htaccess file. You need your file to be located at project/.htaccess

2.) Use the following in your .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* index.php/$0 [PT,L]
```