# CodeIgniter + mod_rewrite url rewrite error

Tags: php, linux, .htaccess, codeigniter, mod-rewrite

I've created an app using CodeIgniter and mod_rewrite (only to abstract the index) on Windows (with WampServer). On that environment, the app works just fine, everything smooth as it should be.
But at the time when I went porting it to the production server (Linux), the rewriting processes just stoped working.

At first glance, it appeard to me that the "case-sensistiveness" of the linux file system was the vilain. But after renaming the files that contained errors, the problem persisted.

The fact is. No matter wich url I call, the rewrite keeps calling the /index.php.

Here is my .htaccess content:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* index.php/$0 [PT,L]
RewriteRule .\svn\* - [F]
```

The folder structure of my app is:

```
doc_root
  - application
    -controllers
       -c.php

  - .htaccess
  - index.php
  (... everything else is codeigniter's default)
```

Comment: Check my answer here, it may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13326577/remove-index-php-of-codeigniter/13326670#13326670

Comment: Nops... Those directives was already defined on my apache/virtual host config.

Comment: Are you sure you have mod_rewrite loaded and that your htaccess file is being read?

Comment: Ok, I will show you one of my .htaccess from a Linux box

Comment: Yep.. In Fact, I can activate mod_rewrite logs whenever I want (that way i noticed that the error was in the mod_rewrite).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
        RewriteEngine On
        RewriteBase /

        RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^$
        RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
        RewriteCond %{HTTPS}s ^on(s)|
        RewriteRule ^ http%1://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

        #Removes access to the system folder by users.
        #Additionally this will allow you to create a System.php controller
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
        RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

        #When your application folder isn't in the system folder
        #This snippet prevents user access to the application folder
        #Submitted by: Fabdrol
        #Rename 'application' to your applications folder name.
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^application.*
        RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

        #Checks to see if the user is attempting to access a valid file,
        #such as an image or css document, if this isn't true it sends the
        #request to index.php
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
        RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
    </IfModule>

    <IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
        # If we don't have mod_rewrite installed, all 404's
        # can be sent to index.php, and everything works as normal.
        # Submitted by: ElliotHaughin

        ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
    </IfModule>
```

Comment: Just to let you know, after "RewriteBase /" the next four lines force www. - you can nix those lines if not needed. The part you're really after is the last three lines of the "IfModule"

Comment: Honestly, i think i've already tried the "^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]" Rule (I'm stuck with this issue for a couple of weeks now), but will try it again ASAP. I'll let you know the results.

Comment: Ok...I was stuck for a couple of days myself before this one worked. I know it's a PITA, so if it doesn't work let's figure out a way for me to send you a full .zip archive with a working blank app. Then you can compare files to see what it might be.

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteBase /
   RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} 200
   RewriteRule .* - [L]



#'system' can be replaced if you have renamed your system folder.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]


#Rename 'application' to your applications folder name.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^application.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]


RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

Taking Kenzo's answer as basis, and digging a little more, I arived at the config above. It didn't quite solved the entire problem by itself, but the rewriting part was solved entirely. The whole problem was caused in one part by the rewrite engine not knowing to redirect properly, and the other part was the "case sensitiveness" of the filesystem. I dont know if it is the best solution, but I created some symbolic links to my main controler and model, and everything worked fine. The symlinks aproach worked cause my controller file name is "c.php", so i created a "C.php" symlink, and every request can be done without worrying the case sensitive.